# Getting Roles from Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, bearer-token

I'm trying to verify a role type from an azure web token. This is my authorization policy.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(o => {
                o.Authority = Configuration["Identity:Authority"];
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });


services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiAccess", policy => {
                    policy.RequireClaim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, "apiAccess");
                });
});
```

I can see within the token provided there is roles with my role type in it. But if I try to access any page in my web app it shows that I am not of the correct role.

```
"roles": [
        "apiAccess"
    ],
```

Comment: policy.RequireClaim is validating the token maps to the role, where are you assigning yourself to a role ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role` resolves to `roles`? What if you used `roles` string directly:

```
policy.RequireClaim("roles", "apiAccess");
```

or use the `.RequireRole` method instead?

```
policy.RequireRole("apiAccess")
```